# Not able to search community users through Global Search from PROD

Tags: partner-communities, search

We have just enabled communities in our PROD org, created Parter enabled Accounts and Parter Users from their Contacts.

We are able to search the records created by Partner Users in PROD  but we are not able to search Partner User individually from Global Search box as a System Administrator.

Any idea how can we achieve this?

Thanks!
Chirag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed the default behaviour. You will see the corresponding Contact records, but not the User record. I don't think there is a way to influence that.

For system admins it's probably better to go via Setup. Using the new Setup Search you can directly search for a User by entering their name in the setup search box.

Comment: Ok I'll try to use this new feature of 'advance setup search'. Thank You